# Line numbers in NSTextView (Lion compliant)

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I am trying to show line numbers in an NSTexView. I was using the solution from http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2008/10/05/displaying-line-numbers-with-nstextview/ but it is no more working with Lion.

Do you know an alternative solution?

Comment: The example you mentioned works fine in Lion. I think it is something you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try again.

Comment: Did you ever find out what this issue what?  Could you describe exactly what the problem was in a little more detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you probably need an updated version of the files for 64bit (Lion).

I [forked the NoodleKit project on GitHub](https://github.com/scottharwell/NoodleKit) and made some changes that I found on the web.  I made some small tweaks, but the changes here mostly came from others on the Internet and the original repo.  The owner of the repo has not updated the NoodleLineNumberview in two years, but I may send a pull request so he will add it to his repo. These classes are working in my Lion projects, so they should work for you.

Update your project with these new files and then try to compile:

- NoodleLineNumberMarker.h
- NoodleLineNumberMarker.m
- NoodleLineNumberView.h
- NoodleLineNumberView.m

If you are using the MarkerLineNumberView that came with an old version of the project, then that will not work here. Just replace those objects with NoodleLineNumberView.